# How to save one file from one path to another path? Without removing file from original path using C#

Tags: c#

I want to save one file from one path to another path.

Eg:

**Original path : C:\File.txt**

**New path : D:\Folder\File.txt**

Can i use:

**File.Move("C:\File.txt", "D:\Folder\File.txt");**

But i think this will remove file from original path. (C#)

Comment: Remember to escape the backslashes in your string either by using another backslash or a @ in front of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

[File.Copy Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Copies an existing file to a new file.

[How to: Copy, Delete, and Move Files and Folders (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Try [`File.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx), i.e.

```
File.Copy(@"C:\File.txt", @"D:\Folder\File.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `File.Copy(@"C:\File.txt", @"D:\Folder\File.txt");`?

Comment: Watch out for those pesky backslashes in your strings. :)

Comment: I corrected it. Just copied parameters from Neil's posting. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx) ?

Answer (score 1):

Then you could use [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy(VS.71).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Try [`File.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just like this below...

```
System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFileName, destFileName);
```